# Make EF Core More Resillient if error occurs with Temporal Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

We have had the error below when calling SaveChangesAsync on Ef Core - error 0x80131904

```
Data modification failed on system-versioned table 'table name' because transaction 
time was earlier at than period start time for affected records.
```

I know that this error relates to the valid from and valid to dates in the history table causing an overlap if there is a lot of activity happening

I know that this error is by design and there is nothing I can do to avoid it really

However, I need a solution for retrying the SaveChangesAsync call if an exception happens, with this message

I think the solution is when the database is initialized

```
options.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
    sqlOptions =>
    {
        sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(MigrationAssemblyName);
        sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(maxRetryCount: 10,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
            new List<int>()
            {
                80131904
            });
            sqlOptions.CommandTimeout(240);
    });
```

The parameter

```
new List<int>()
{
  80131904
};
```

Is the change however, Im not sure if this is correct or if there is a better approach to retry in this situation?

Is this number correct? It seems to be hex but converting this to a number would give a number bigger than can be held by int

This error number doesnt seem to relate specifically to the error message and it feels like this is already an error number that would be classed as transient?

The error number appears to be hex but when converted out of hex its too big to store as an int

Has anyone had experience with this?

Paul

Comment: You can take a lock on the whole table to prevent any other transaactions sneaking in. This does have the side effect of reducing concurrency by blocking the whole table obviously.

Comment: How would I even know what tables to lock given that SaveChangesAsync saves all changes to the database since the last call? That could be loads of tables. Would that not also crash other connections out who try to update the locked tables?

Comment: You could use the `ChangeTracker` to find which entities are being changed. Yes that could be a lot of tables in some situations, and yes it will block other connections until the transaction is finished.

Comment: Yes thats what I am worried about - blocking the tables could cause major issues for other connections and exceptions elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not quite correct. The SQL error number is [`13535`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors-13000-to-13999?view=sql-server-ver16) not `80131904` (which is just the hex of the `SqlException`'s HResult). You can see the error number in  the [`exception.Number`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) property.

```cs
options.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
    sqlOptions =>
    {
        sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(MigrationAssemblyName);
        sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
            maxRetryCount: 10,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
            new []{ 13535 }
        );
        sqlOptions.CommandTimeout(240);
    });
```

The only other alternative is to use some kind of locking mechanism. For example you could add an explicit command inside the same transaction

```
SELECT TOP (1) 1 AS dummy
FROM Table WITH (UPDLOCK, TABLOCK);
```

which will prevent any modifications while still allowing `SELECT` queries.

Alternatively you could use [`sp_getapplock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to gate access to the modification procedure: again this will block anyone else trying to get the same lock, but allow anyone who does not.

---

Note that it's possible this error was not related to other transactions. If your `DEFAULT` constraint for the `PERIOD` columns is not precise enough then you can get rounding errors on your own rows. Make sure to always use `SYSUTCDATETIME()` to prevent problems.

Comment: Thanks where did you find that number from?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors-13000-to-13999?view=sql-server-ver16 and a bit of googling. I knew the one you had was wrong, as mentioned.